# getting started designing satellite projection raster

Tags: qgis, gdal, coordinate-system, gdalwarp, d3

How do I get started designing a map with a satellite projection like this:http://bl.ocks.org/joyrexus/6619251. So far using d3 I've created a map of North Africa w/ topojson and tiles from Mapbox but I don't know how to design a static satellite projected terrain raster layer of the areas and match it up with the vector layer. Is there

Comment: The end of your question is missing...